# React: why is the state returned from useState stays the same when the initializer function gets called on every re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-bash-qj7ld?file=/src/App.js

So I have a component like this

```js
const fn = () => {
  console.log("useState");
  return ["string"];
};

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const [nonprimitive, setNonprimitive] = useState(fn());

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
  }, [nonprimitive]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Counter {counter}</button>
      <div>{nonprimitive[0]}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

every time I clicked on the button, the counter will increase and the component will re-render. and then `fn()` will be called again, then it will return an array. and the `useEffect` is triggered when `nonprimitive` is changing. I have two questions:

1. why is that `useEffect` gets triggered only once, not for every subsequent calls? `nonprimitive` is an array, which is a non primitive type, so it should be different every time even when the string item inside of it stays the same. It seems like React is doing some deep comparison under the hood.
2. Why is the `useState` gets printed out twice whenever the component re-renders? i.e.   `console.log("useState");` inside `fn` gets called twice when I hit the button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> why is that `useEffect` gets triggered only once, not for every subsequent calls? `nonprimitive` is an array, which is a non primitive type, so it should be different every time even when the string item inside of it stays the same. It seems like React is doing some deep comparison under the hood.

The whole point of `useState` is to persist values across renders of your component. The first time your component renders, `useState(fn())` is called and `nonprimitive` gets the value `["string"]`. On subsequent renders, `useState(fn())` is called again (because, after all, it is still a standard function call, and so the logging happens again), but React knows that it's not your first render, so it throws away the argument (the return value of `fn`) and instead returns the previously stored value, which is referentially the same.

If you don't want React to call your initial state creation on every render (for example, if your initial state is very complex or time-consuming to calculate), you can pass it a function which it will only call on the initial render.

```
const [nonprimitive, setNonprimitive] = useState(() => fn());
```

In your case, since the initial state is already wrapped in a function, you can equivalently write

```
const [nonprimitive, setNonprimitive] = useState(fn);
```

> Why is the `useState` gets printed out twice whenever the component re-renders? i.e. `console.log("useState");` inside `fn` gets called twice when I hit the button.

If you look in your index.js, you'll notice that your `App` component is wrapped in `<React.StrictMode>`. [React strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) will intentionally run certain renders more than once to help you catch side effects and hook violations in your code.

Comment: Upvoting for your description of useState

Comment: thanks for the reply. so you pointed out that because React knows that `fn` is not being called for the first time, so it throws away the return value of it and instead returns the previous state. However I wonder if `fn` returns values that can change overtime, for example, maybe a random number, React would still disregard the returned value from it? I thought React would do some comparison for the returned values but it sounds like React doesn't even bother to compare the returned values from `fn`

Comment: The argument you pass to `useState` is the **initial** value only. If you want to change the value of `nonprimitive`, use `setNonprimitive`.

Answer (score -1):

The double rendering is a result of `React.StrictMode`:

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions:
>
> - Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate methods
> - Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
> - Function component bodies
> - State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
> - **Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer**

If you remove `React.StrictMode` from your index file, you will stop seeing the double rendering.

As for the `useEffect`, you are correct. There is a deep comparison happening. React is able to infer that the array has not changed unless elements of the array have changed. Also remember that anything provided to `useState` is only set on the first render, so your array isn't actually changing until you call the setter, even though the `fn` is called multiple times.

React strict mode docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html

Comment: React does not perform deep comparison, the effect doesn't run twice because the state is never changed and the (referentially) same array is being returned.